# How can I reset a model and view in PySide / PyQt / Qt?

Tags: qt, pyqt, reset, pyside

Adding and deleting rows are very straight forward, but how about if I want to completely reset a model and view?

In my particular example I have a dataset shown in a model and view, and every now and then the dataset in the model in its entirety is thrown out and a new one is put in its place. How do I do this most efficiently?

(It might be worthwhile to point out that I am using a model & proxymodel & view.)

Answer (score 2):

[beginResetModel()](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginResetModel) and [endResetModel()](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#endResetModel).

Comment: +1, but just to point out you must do the actual deletion/blanking of the data between sending these two signals. Doing this allows you to clean out the underlying data without using the usual setData() mechanism.

Comment: Hard to tell based on the question.